# how get PDO error with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

please help how to i get error from PDO if my POST can't insert into database. When i run just say "sukse tersimpan" but no data at database.

this JS code

```
$(document).on('submit','#daftar',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#loading').show();
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
$('.help-block').remove();
var formObj = $(this);
var formData= new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: '../user/simpan_daftar.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    contentType : false,
    cache       : false,
    processData : false,
    success:function (data) {
        if (!data.success){
            if (data.errors.nama){
                $('#nama-group').addClass('has-error');
                $('#nama-group').append('<span class="help-block">'+data.errors.nama+'</span>');
                alert(data.errors.nama);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
            else if (data.errors.nope){
                $('#nope-group').addClass('has-error');
                $('#nope-group').append('<span class="help-block">'+data.errors.nope+'</span>');
                alert(data.errors.nope);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
            else if (data.errors.email){
                $('#email-group').addClass('has-error');
                $('#email-group').append('<span class="help-block">'+data.errors.email+'</span>');
                alert(data.errors.email);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
            else if (data.errors.sandi){
                $('#sandi-group').addClass('has-error');
                $('#sandi-group').append('<span class="help-block">'+data.errors.sandi+'</span>');
                alert(data.errors.sandi);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
            else if (data.errors){
                alert("error occured");
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            $('#loading').hide();
            alert(data.msg);
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});});
```

this simpan_daftar.php

```
<?php
require ('../autolod.php');
$errors = array();
$data   = array();
if (isset($_POST)||empty($_POST)===false) {
    $nama       = $_POST['nama'];
    $nope       = $_POST['nope'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $pass       = $_POST['sandi'];
    $email_code = $email_code = uniqid('code_',true); // Creating a unique string.
        //if (empty($akses)===true){$errors['akses']='Akses belum dipilih';}
    if (empty($nama)===true){$errors['nama']='Nama belum diisi';}
    if (empty($nope)===true){$errors['nope']='Nomor handphone belum diisi';}
    if (empty($email)===true){$errors['email']='E-mail belum diisi';}
        else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false) {$errors['email']='Silahkan isi alamat E-mail dengan benar';}
        else if ($users->user_exists($email) === true){$errors['email']='E-mail sudah pernah terdaftar';}
    if (empty($pass)===true){$errors['sandi']='Sandi belum diisi';}     
        else if ((($pass)===$nama)===true){$errors['sandi']='Sandi tidak boleh sama dengan nama Anda';}
        else if (strlen($pass)< 6 ){$errors['sandi']='Sandi minimal 6 karakter';}
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      $data['success'] = false;
      $data['errors'] = $errors;
}
else{
    $data['success'] = true;
    $_POST = $users->simpan_daftar($akses,$nama,$nope,$email,$pass,$email_code);
    $data['msg'] = 'sukses tersimpan';
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and this class for execute into database

```
<?php 
Class Users Extends Mailer
{
    private $conn;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new Database();
        $this->conn = $this->conn->Config();
    }
    //records activities
    public function schedule()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
        //date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+1, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));WITA
        //date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));WIT
        $this->timelogin = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");//set datetime
        //set day
        $weeks = array("Minggu","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu");
        $days  = date("w"); 
        $this->daylogin  = $weeks[$days];//get day on current
        $this->getIP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get ip address
    }
    public function simpan_daftar($akses,$nama,$nope,$email,$pass,$email_code)
    {
        global $bcrypt; // making the $bcrypt variable global so we can use here
        $this->schedule();
        $getBrowser=$this->get_browser_name();
        $password = $bcrypt->genHash($pass);//generated encrypt password
        $qry=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_list (
            akses_id,
            user_nama,
            user_phone,
            user_email,
            user_password,
            create_time,
            user_status,
            user_ip,
            user_browser,
            email_code) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $qry->bindValue(1, $akses);
        $qry->bindValue(2, $nama);
        $qry->bindValue(3, $nope);
        $qry->bindValue(4, $email);
        $qry->bindValue(5, $password);
        $qry->bindValue(6, $this->timelogin);
        $qry->bindValue(7, 'non_aktif');
        $qry->bindValue(8, $this->getIP);
        $qry->bindValue(9, 'belum tersedia');
        $qry->bindValue(10, $email_code);
        try {
            $qry->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            die($exception->getMessage());  
        }
    }
    }
```

I can't see error PDO why my POST data can't insert into database. No problem with my JS code.

i think the problem at this code below

```
else{
    $data['success'] = true;
    $_POST = $users->simpan_daftar($akses,$nama,$nope,$email,$pass,$email_code);
    $data['msg'] = 'sukses tersimpan';
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

and this code

```
try {
            $qry->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            die($exception->getMessage());  
        }
```

many thanks for help my problem.

sorry for my Bad English

Comment: I wouldn't recommend dumping the PDO error out because if this goes to production it will be a security liability.

Comment: You need to put `pdo` errors reporting on to begin with, like so `$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. Please keep in mind what @Machavity has mentioned.

Comment: @Machavity i also think like that. i do not dumping PDO error out, but i want to just get error with Firebug Extension, but at Firebug just say "sukse tersimpan".

Comment: @Nytrix thank you so much for your guide, I have get this error.

Comment: @Nytrix if use PDO errors reporting as dumping PDO error out, can you give other recomendation for solve my problem??

thanks before

Comment: The questions is, what is the `error` you are getting? I can't see anything wrong in your query in a quick sweep.

Comment: @Nytrix I mean is there any suggestion for the future so i've got kind of error (database error) and only me who can see the error. Thank you.

Comment: @MardinoIsmail You should use it until it's live for people to see, you could just let you see it through blocking other ip's then yours.

Comment: @Nytrix. Thank you very much for the suggestion. 

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help.